# Android: Record video for 30 second and after 30 second record audio only

Tags: android, camera

I have requirement in application where i need to record video for 30 second and then only record audio without stopping recording. How can i achieve it? I am using
[Camerview](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) 
library to record video. Shall i change my implementation to surface view?

I have implementation using cameraview library as below. Current implement work to capture video but not fulfill my requirement.

`<com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        app:cameraAudio="on"
        app:cameraCropOutput="false"
        app:cameraFacing="back"
        app:cameraFlash="off"
        app:cameraGestureLongTap="none"
        app:cameraGesturePinch="zoom"
        app:cameraGestureScrollHorizontal="exposureCorrection"
        app:cameraGestureScrollVertical="none"
        app:cameraGestureTap="focus"
        app:cameraGrid="off"
        app:cameraJpegQuality="100"
        app:cameraPlaySounds="true"
        app:cameraSessionType="video"
        app:cameraVideoQuality="max480p" />`

```
 private void captureVideo() {
    if (camera.getSessionType() != SessionType.VIDEO) {
        return;
    }
    videoPath = getContext().getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
    camera.setVideoCodec(VideoCodec.DEVICE_DEFAULT);
    camera.setVideoQuality(VideoQuality.MAX_480P);
    camera.startCapturingVideo(new File(videoPath));
}
```

Comment: Hello Mahesh, what have you tried already? Looking at your StackOverflow reputation I do not think I have to link you to a "how to ask a question" site. Does your current implementation work?

Comment: @ZUNJAE I have updated question for more understanding.

Answer (score 3):

For recording video up to 30 sec.

Try this below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: that will only capture video for 30 second. how to keep capturing audio